# Have Typescript style comments for C# code with IntelliSense

Tags: c#, typescript, comments, intellisense

I am working with C# in VSCode and would like to have intelliSense in my classes, properties and methods. I am used to write it with Typescript that looks something like this:

```
  /**
  * // TODO: do not forget to comment "someMethod"
  * Brief description of this method
  * @param nameOfParam1 description of this parameter's purpose
  * @returns describe what is returning
  */
  someMethod(nameOfParam1 : string): string { ... }
```

With Visual Studio Code I even get some good automatic colors for these comments. I find C# XML comments very ugly and bloaty.

Is there a way to use this same comment style for C# and have intelliSense work too?

Comment: Have you checked this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20767)?

Comment: Yes, I searched for extensions in VSCode that could help. There are a lot but none that would allow me to use intellisense on C# with some other type of commenting. I also went to C# documentation to see what alternatives there are to XML comments. Didn't find anything that would fit me :/.

Answer (score 1):

> I find C# XML comments very ugly and bloaty.

There is no alternatives - XML Comments is part of language standard